# Relative div is under my fixed div at the top

Tags: html, tags, overlap

I have a div that is fixed like so

```
.div1{
     position:fixed;
}
```

I also have another div that I want to fall lower then this div that I have coded like so

```
.div2{
     postion:relative;
}
```

div2 is ending up right behind div1. Do I need to position the second div? Like so..

```
 top:(number of pixels of first div)px;
```

Comment: close - Use margin-top instead of top

Comment: cool. will post comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

close - Use margin-top instead of top

```
margin-top:(number of pixels of first div)px;
```